# Enhanced Eclipse file search plugin

Tags: eclipse, file, search

Existing eclipse file search has few pitfalls,

- Can not search based on file path pattern
- Can not search based on file exclusing pattern
- Can not search for directory names [say search for all maven generated target directories and mark them as derived ]

Are there any plugins that extend to cover these functionalities, or I need to wait for newer version of eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a search plugin which has those feature (like an exclude pattern).

There was a [SOC project in 2007](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_search_plugin%3a_providing_a_better,_faster,_more_relevant_Eclipse_search.) to enhance that search, but the result, in term of exclusion pattern for instance, will be available in Eclipse4 (see [bug 252996](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=252996)).